# Firebase Reference Query on Root

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a student-teacher private messenger application using Firebase and I can insert data inside the root like this:
[image: my Firebase DB]

The usernames are retrived from a MySQL database, so I just only need to make a query. I would like to get only the data inside a ListView where chatID equals to my generated ID. I've searched in a lot of places like [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) but can't make the **DatabaseReference** working. Here is my code:

```
private void displayStudentChatMessages() {
    listofMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_msg);

    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<BubbleMessageStudent>(this, BubbleMessageStudent.class, R.layout.item_chat_right, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, BubbleMessageStudent model, int position) {
            TextView studentUsername = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user_sender);
            TextView studentMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView studentSentDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_usertime);

            studentUsername.setText(model.getStudentUsername());
            studentMessage.setText(model.getStudentMessage());

            studentSentDate.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd%n(HH:mm:ss)", model.getStudentMessageTime()));
        }
    };

    listofMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    listofMessages.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you giving parameters to `getReference()`?

Comment: But how can you get the root as reference?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are having? `getReference("chatapp-autosiskola")` is what I meant, but that may not be necessary

Comment: Side question: If the data initially came from MySQL, how did it end up in Firebase? Or do you not have an API over that?

Comment: Nothing but I need that child element or elements, where the chatID equals my chatID

Comment: I have a login method where the data came from a MySQL database, because I don't want Facebook or other authenticate

Comment: Did you try `if (model.getChatId().equals(yourChatID)) { ... }`?

Comment: The real solution here is to fix your database to put the `chatID` as the key of the element in place of the `Klu...` data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @cricket_007 commented, you'll need a query to get the chat messages with the correct ID:

```
rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
chatQuery = rootRef.orderByChild("chatID").equalTo("teststudent-testteacher...");
adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<BubbleMessageStudent>(
  this, BubbleMessageStudent.class, R.layout.item_chat_right, chatQuery)...
```

With this code your adapter will only show the messages with the correct chatID.

But in general your data model seems suboptimal. You've essentially mapped a table from your MySQL database into a node in Firebase. It probably works for now, but there are better ways to do this mapping.

In Firebase (and many other NoSQL databases) you should model your data for what you show on the screen. So if your app shows a chat room, which is a list of messages with the same chatID, then you should model precisely that in the database: a list of messages with the same chat ID:

```
chatId1
  chat1Message1: ...
  chat1Message2: ...
  chat1Message3: ...
chatId2
  chat2Message1: ...
  chat2Message2: ...
  chat2Message3: ...
```

With this structure you don't need a query to read the messages for a specific chat room. Instead you can directly access the node where they're under:

```
chatRoom = rootRef.child("teststudent-testteacher...");
adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<BubbleMessageStudent>(
  this, BubbleMessageStudent.class, R.layout.item_chat_right, chatRoom)...
```

This results in much better scalability.

I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).